# Passing values into a Vector3f

Tags: c++, class

I want to be able to pass 3 values to an object which are then stored in a class called Vector3f. Vector3f has x,y,z values;

I.e:

```
Object(Vector3f Position); //Class constructor

Object myObject(0,10,20); //Declare object
```

Is this right?

Or would I have to do:

```
Vector3f vect(0,10,20);
Object myObject(vect);
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constructor takes a single `Vector3f` argument, you'll have to pass it a single `Vector3f` object, and three floats won't work. But you can write that in a single line:

```
Object myObject(Vector3f(0, 10, 20));
```

You could also declare an additional constructor that accepts three floats instead.

Comment: Or `Object myObject({ 0, 10, 20 })` uniform initialization FTW.

Comment: @mfontanini In the compilers which support it.

Answer (score 2):

the second one because multiple arguments constructor cannot be implicit converted

although with `C++11` you can do `Object myObject({0, 10, 20});`

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information, you should do as your second way:

```
Vector3f vect(0,10,20);
Object myObject(vect);
```

Or

```
 Vector3f myObject(vect(0,10,20));
```

This will first create an object of `Vector3f` then pass it as parameter to `Object` class's constructor, which takes object of `Vector3f` as parameter.